# Python list that outputs numbers inputted backwards

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop

I have a need for a code that asks for input of 5 pos numbers, then outputs these numbers backwards. I would like to use a while loop. This is what I've come up with so far, but it the second while loop doesn't work.

```
positiveNum = 0
SIZE = 5
numberList= []
ARRAY_LIMIT = SIZE -1

while len(numberList) < SIZE :
    positiveNum = input("Enter a positive number:")
    numberList.append(positiveNum)
while int(positiveNum) >= 0:
    print(numberList[positiveNum])
    positiveNum -= 1
```

Comment: pay attention, you are using positiveNum both as the index of the list that needs to be accesses and both as the actual number given by the user. That is if the user gives you "100", you will try to access numberList[100], while numberList might have only one number inside instead

Comment: in idiomatic python a while loop is not the right construct to use. Even in other languages you would generally use a while loop when you don't know how many items you would be iterating over. For both loops you know how many. As an educational thing its fine but don't think thats the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be iterating on length of numberList and not positive num.
Basically modify second while loop to this.

```
 i = SIZE; 
 while i>0: 
        print(numberList[i-1])
        i=i-1
```

Answer (score 0):

On the second loop, you are using the same positiveNum variable without reseting it to the size of the array, try:

```
SIZE = 5
numberList= []
ARRAY_LIMIT = SIZE -1

while len(numberList) < SIZE :
    positiveNum = input("Enter a positive number:")
    numberList.append(positiveNum)
index = SIZE - 1
while index >= 0:
    print(numberList[index])
    index -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that `input` returns a `string` so you need to cast it to an `int` if you want to index with it. You are likely getting the following error.

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
# Won't work with string
numberList[positiveNum]
positiveNum -= 1
# Need to cast to int first
positiveNum = int(input("Enter a positive number:"))
```

Converting it in your while loop condition will only work for the condition, it does not change that value in the variable to an `int`, it is still a `string`

```
# Works only once
while int(positiveNum) >= 0:
```

Now the next issue is that you are using `positiveNum` as the index number. This will cause an `IndexError` if the last number entered is greater than `SIZE`, say 100.

```
SIZE = 5
number_lst = []

while len(number_lst) < SIZE:
    # Should perform error checking if you must have positive numbers
    num = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))
    number_lst.append(num)

# Output backwards using while
i = len(number_lst) - 1
while i >= 0:
    print(number_lst[i])
    i -= 1
```

Here is also a couple of for loop alternatives

```
# Output backwards using for
for item in number_lst[::-1]:
    print(item)

for item in reversed(number_lst):
    print(item)

for i in range(len(number_lst) - 1, -1):
    print(number_lst[i])

for i in reversed(range(len(number_lst))):
    print(number_lst[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using while loops:

```
size = 5
number_list = []

while len(number_list) < size:
    number_list.append(int(input("Enter a positive number: ")))
i = 1
while i <= size:
    print(number_list[size - i])
    i += 1
```

Using a for loop for the second loop:

```
size = 5
number_list = []

while len(number_list) < size:
    number_list.append(int(input("Enter a positive number: ")))
for i in number_list[::-1]:
    print(i)
```

Using two for loops, which would be more sensible in this case:

```
size = 5
number_list = []

for _ in range(size):
    number_list.append(int(input("Enter a positive number: ")))
for i in number_list[::-1]:
    print(i)
```